# How to convert a scala Seq[] to a Javascript Array?

Tags: javascript, json, scala, playframework-2.0

I try to pass a data Seq[] in a play template, and according to the Play Framework doc (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson), you can convert this into a Json array. I tried this :

```
$(function() {
  var jsArray = JSON.toJSON(customerList);
    alert("Customer 1 :  " + jsArray[0]);
    for (var e in jsArray) {
      setCustomers(e["name"], e["id"]);
    }
  });
```

But chrome console show me an error message :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON'
```

I tried to import `play.api.libs.json._` but it doesn't work too.

Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(function() {
  var jsArray = @Json.toJson(customerList);
    alert("Customer 1 :  " + jsArray[0]);
    for (var e in jsArray) {
      setCustomers(e["name"], e["id"]);
    }
  });
```

The @ will mark the remaining code as scala code to be executed. without the @ the code will be sent as is to the browser and the browser doesn't know play' scala json library

According to your comment, `customerList` has type `Seq[Customer]` therefore you must be sure to have a deserializer for `Customer` in the template scope.

Assuming you have the `Customer` class defined in the `models`package and you read [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception) you would have a `Customer`object with the implicit formats defined alongside your `Customer`. In which case you need `import models.Customer` at the top of your template.

A sample Customer definition would look like 
    package models

```
case class Customer(name:String,...)
object Customer{
  import play.api.libs.json._
  implicit val customerFormats=Json.format[Customer]
}
```

if your `Customer`type depends on other custom types, you will need to import or define Json serializers for these too for instance :

```
package models
case class CustomerAddress(street:String,postCode:String)
case class Customer(name:String,address:CustomerAddress,...)
object Customer{
  import play.api.libs.json._
  // need to define 2 json formats : 1 for CustomerAddress and 1 for Customer
  implicit val customerAddressFormats=Json.format[CustomerAddress]
  implicit val customerFormats=Json.format[Customer]
}
```

According to your comments, the `Customer` class is defined in another project which may not depend on Play, in which case you can still define custom serializers in another object

```
package models
object IdentityAccessComponentFormats{
    import play.api.libs.json._
    implicit val customerAddressFormats=Json.format[CustomerAddress]
    implicit val customerFormats=Json.format[Customer]
}
```

then add

```
import models.IdentityAccessComponentFormats._
```

at the top of your template

Comment: I've already tried, and play displays : `not found: value JSON`

Comment: The correct syntax is Json (uppercase 'J' lowercase for 'son') JSON is the name of the javascript JSON library entrypoint. Json is the name of play' scala JSON library entrypoint.

Comment: Now I've this : `No Json deserializer found for type Seq[Customer]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.` I tried `Json.stringtify` but no result.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect the fact that your customerList is a Seq[Customer]

Comment: I see what you mean, but my Customer class comes from a library I've developped (in scala with SBT), so I have implemented it in my Play project, and in my template I import it like this : `@(customerList: Seq[com.example.identityaccesscomponent.models.customer.Customer])`

Comment: add `import com.example.identityaccesscomponent.models.customer.Customer` at the top of your template. if you have a serializer defined it will be imported in the scope. Using the fully qualified name of the class in the template parameters will not import the formats from the companion object in the template scope

Comment: I've download spray-json library for my sbt project, and I can't find the equivalent function to format Customer class (`jsonFormat()` want a String parameter)

Comment: I don't know spray-json well enough to answer that but you don't need it.  If you don't want to add the play-json dependency to your identityaccesscomponent project to depend on play, you can always define the serializers after the fact in your play project: see my updated answer ...

Comment: I found how to convert my object list, I've created 2 methods to convert object and objects list to JSON : `def customerToJson(customer: CustomerInfo) = {
    JsObject(
      "id" -> JsNumber(customer.id.id) ::
        "name" -> JsString(customer.name) :: Nil
    )
  }

  def customersToJson(customers: Seq[CustomerInfo]): JsArray = {
    JsArray(
      customers.map {
        customer => customerToJson(customer)
      }
    )
  }`